# How to delete a ets entry based on non key part

Tags: erlang

I have a etc table ‘table’ as {key,[val1,val2]}
I selected this data from the table using

```
ets:select(table,[{{‘$1','$2'},[],['$$']}]).                                
 [[key,["val1",<<"12">>]],
 [key,["val2",<<"6">>]],
 [key,["val3",<<"16">>]]]
```

I want to delete a entry matching the part [val1,val2] using this

```
ets:select_delete(table,[{{‘$1','$2'},[{'==','$2',["val1",<<"12">>]}],['$$']}]).
 0
```

But still when I run select again I get

```
ets:select(table,[{{‘$1','$2'},[],['$$']}]).                                
 [[key,["val1",<<"12">>]],
 [key,["val2",<<"6">>]],
 [key,["val3",<<"16">>]]]
```

How can I delete this entry based on the non key part?

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue and resolved it just by wrapping `true` in brackets.

Here's the solution:

```
ets:select_delete(table,[{{'$1','$2'},[{'==','$2',["val1",<<"12">>]}],[true]}]).
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ets:select_delete` documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#select_delete-2) says:

> The match specification has to return the atom `true` if the object is to be deleted. No other return value gets the object deleted. So one cannot use the same match specification for looking up elements as for deleting them.

So try this:

```
ets:select_delete(table,[{{'$1','$2'},[{'==','$2',["val1",<<"12">>]}],true}]).
```

`ets:select_delete` returns the number of records it deleted, so hopefully it should return 1 this time.

Comment: I used `ets:select_delete(table,[{{‘$1','$2'},[{'==','$2',["val1",<<"12">>]}],true}]).` which gives a ` * 1: illegal character ` error.

Comment: Oops, a smart quotation mark crept in. I edited the answer, please try again. (That is, the single quote right before `$1` was not a "real" single quote.)

Comment: I tried the updated command but I got this ` ets:select_delete(table,[{{'$1','$2'},[{'==','$2',["val1",<<"12">>]}],true}]).              ** exception error: bad argument
     in function  ets:select_delete/2
        called as ets:select_delete(table,
                                    [{{'$1','$2'},[{'==','$2',["val1",<<"12">>]}],true}])`
Plus the ets:select/2 command also give the same error now.

Comment: I think by running the command with atom 'true' my table got deleted instead(I don't know how though).

Comment: If you're creating the table in the shell, and then run something that crashes, the table will be deleted as it was owned by the shell process that crashed.

Comment: ok I got the reason for table deletion, but any pointers on why did it crash with bad argument in the first place.Is the match_pattern made is incorrect?